# Send json format through link in java

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, tomcat

The thing that I am trying to do is this:
I have made a Click class wich looks likes this:

```
public class Click {
private int id;
private int x;
private int y;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}
```

}

and I fill it up like this:

```
public class ClickService implements ClickServiceInterface {
Random r = new Random();
@Override
public Click getClickDetail() {
    Click c = new Click();
    c.setId(r.nextInt(99)+1);
    c.setX(r.nextInt(1919)+1); //values 1-1920
    c.setY(r.nextInt(1079)+1); //values 1-1080
    return c;
}
```

}

making use of this interface:

```
public interface ClickServiceInterface {
public Click getClickDetail();
```

}

But now I am kind of stuck becaus I don't really know how to put that into a real Spring MVC project.
where I can go to a link like this for example:

```
http://localhost:8080/Spring4-1/data/click
```

I need the output to be something like this everytime I poll to the link I try to create:

```
{"id":1,"x":987, "y":654}
```

Thanks in advance,
your fellow techie

Answer (score 0):

You need to define Controller that will expose your service. See following [spring guide](http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/).

Code sample from there:

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                            String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```